# update a column with sequential Values

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Hi Guys I have a table with Multiple column and rows my First Column B2kID is blank I need it Update with values Like:

```
VC1
VC2
VC3
VC4
 .
 .
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ROWNUM` to get a unique number for a record:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = 'VC' || ROWNUM
WHERE columnName IS NULL
;
```

Comment: Thank you very Much. that was Accurate and to the Point

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`rownum` pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) to get a unique identifier for each of the affected rows, and just use it along with the [`||` concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm) in a regular `UPDATE` sentence:

```
UPDATE myTable SET B2kID = 'VC' || rownum;
```

Here is a sample [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74596/1).

Answer (score 1):

The PL/SQL block provided in the following link can be useful.
http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Creating-a-sequence-for-a-varchar-in-PL/SQL

Comment: Care to add some more information to your answer, do not provide just a link, add your code solution with some meaningful explanation